# Reading the contents of the XLS file using ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, excel, unity-game-engine, exceldatareader

I use the following code to read the contents of the xls file using ExcelDataReader.

```
List<string> excelFiles = GetExcelFileNamesInDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath);

        for (int i = 0; i < excelFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open(excelFiles[i], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // Auto-detect format, supports:
                //  - Binary Excel files (2.0-2003 format; *.xls)
                //  - OpenXml Excel files (2007 format; *.xlsx)

                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {

                    // Choose one of either 1 or 2:
                    fileLog.text = reader.Name;

                    // 1. Use the reader methods
                    do
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            // reader.GetDouble(0);
                        }
                    } while (reader.NextResult());

                    // 2. Use the AsDataSet extension method
                    var result = reader.AsDataSet();


                    // The result of each spreadsheet is in result.Tables
                }
            }
        }
```

there is one excel file and hence the code passes the for loop. Unfortunately, the code does not cross the line `using (var stream..` and it ends right before creating reader using ExcelReaderFactory. am I missing any reference ?

Comment: It would be interesting to see GetExcelFileNamesInDirectory method definition. More likely the responses from the method are not valid filenames. Could you add definition of GetExcelFileNamesInDirectory to the OP

Comment: What do you mean by "ends right before creating reader"? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: you should start by putting a try/catch block around the entire thing. Your process or user may not have sufficient permission to open the file, it may be read-locked by another process or the path is wrong. Also we do not know what `GetExcelFileNamesInDirectory` returns. The strings returned from that method could be invalid file paths.